# Asp.Net Core: should I use AddScoped or AddSingleton on a cache service

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, caching

In an asp.net core application I have a dependency-injected cache service, which is essentially a wrapper around the built-in MemoryCache.

Here is the example class that gets cached, it contains lists of some enums that are always used by the web application:

```
public class GetEnums
{
    public List<MyEnum1> Ones { get; set; }
    public List<MyEnum2> Twos { get; set; }
}
```

Here is an example method call on my cache service class, it simply retrieves the GetEnums class:

```
public class CacheService: ICacheService
{
    private IMemoryCache MemoryCache {get;set;}
    public CacheService(IMemoryCache memoryCache)
    {
        MemoryCache = memoryCache;
    }
    public GetEnums GetEnums()
    {
        if (MemoryCache.TryGetValue("GetEnums", out GetEnums getEnums))
            return getEnums;

        getEnums = MyRepository.GetEnums();
        MemoryCache.Set(CacheKeys.GetEnums, getEnums, _enumMemoryCacheEntryOptions);

        return getEnums;
    }
}
```

In my ConfigureServices method I want to make this class a dependency-injected service. Should I use AddScoped or AddSingleton? That is to say, should I do this?

```
services.AddScoped(<ICacheService,CacheService>);
```

Or this?

```
services.AddSingleton(<ICacheService,CacheService>);
```

I have two questions.

One, if I choose AddScoped: my guess is that since my cache service class is merely a wrapper around the MemoryCache, the sole difference would be the slight overhead used to create a cache service object with every web request (AddScoped) vs. one instance for the application (AddSingleton). I'm guessing the .Net runtime will **not** create a separate instance of the MemoryCache if I use AddScoped.

Two, if I choose AddSingleton, do I need to add "lock" statements inside each method on my cache service around the "MemoryCache.Set" call, like so:

```
    private readonly object _cachelock = new ();
    public GetEnums GetEnums()
    {
        if (MemoryCache.TryGetValue(CacheKeys.GetEnums, out GetEnums getEnums))
            return getEnums;

        lock(_cachelock)
        {
            if (MemoryCache.TryGetValue(CacheKeys.GetEnums, out getEnums))
                return getEnums;

            getEnums = MyRepository.GetEnums();
            MemoryCache.Set(CacheKeys.GetEnums, getEnums, _enumMemoryCacheEntryOptions);
        }

        return getEnums;
    }
```

Comment: What would be the point of using ```AddScoped``` for this?

Comment: No "point" @IdsvanderZee, I'm just new to Core and want to flesh out the best pattern as I move forward, I need to understand how this works.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

When you register the Memory cache with `services.AddMemoryCache()` it's added as a Singleton, so it would seem logical to register your service as a Singleton as well.

[Source code](https://github.com/aspnet/Caching/blob/9db2c381b19ff2aeb8d6783f145c3c41e1529b78/src/Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Memory/MemoryCacheServiceCollectionExtensions.cs#L30)

MemoryCache is also thread safe so there should be no reason to add a lock. If multiple calls to Set() are made for a given key, it will simply update the exist value.

[MemoryCache Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.caching.memorycache?view=dotnet-plat-ext-5.0#thread-safety)

Comment: Thanks @RichMercer. I know the MemoryCache is thread-safe. I'm wondering if I need a "lock" statement to prevent potentially-wasteful multiple-filling of the cached object (eg 4 threads find the cached item null, so all 4 threads call the method to set it). My question was, do I need to worry about that?

Comment: Personally I wouldn't add the lock as you're not likely to see a meaningful performance benefit.

Comment: Just for anyone who comes across this answer and is wondering about services.AddMemoryCache: in most cases there is no need to explicitly call services.AddMemoryCache(). For example, if you are already calling services.AddMvc() or services.AddRazorPages() that call is made for you.